# WPF Inventor Add-In Project Could not Load 'Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors'

Tags: prism

I created a WPF project with

TargetFramework - **.NET 6.0**
NugetPackage - **Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors**

Used Interaction in the View to for Trigger Action

```xml
<ComboBox x:Name="Desc" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" IsEditable="True" ItemsSource="{Binding desc}"
    SelectedIndex="{Binding binddes}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DescSelectionChangedCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding  ElementName=Desc, Path=SelectedIndex}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ComboBox>
```

I added the Above project as dependency to Inventor Add-In Project
build was successful

[image]

I am creating a instance of Main Window for the WPF project in the Inventor Add-In Project

Following Error occurs in the WPF Project
[image]

Removing the Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviour Package...
and removing the Interaction Trigger Command Coding

```xml
<ComboBox x:Name="Desc" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" IsEditable="True" ItemsSource="{Binding desc}"
    SelectedIndex="{Binding binddes}">
</ComboBox>
```

The WPF Main Window Instance is working fine and Main Window is displayed.